# connect to amazon RDS on scaleway server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wanna try amazon RDS for my project, so I created micro instance in amazon AWS. I am new to AWS, I added my server IP to security group and VPC. I tried to connect from server:

```
psql -h digrin.asdada.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d digrin -U my_username -W
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "digrin.asdada.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.71.212.12) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I can login from localhost, so I was going through amazon AWS settings multiple times and added IP of server everywhere I thought might be causing problems. No luck.

Then I tried to login from another server, which IP I did not add anywhere to AWS and I did connect successfully - so my database is pulicly available.
So I thought my server provider is blocking 5432 port or something such. I created ticket with them (Scaleway) and this is what I got:

> Hello,
>
> Please understand that we do not provide support regarding software management / Firewall configuration.
> On our end, nothing is locked network-wise on any port unless you modify your security group's configuration.

I don't understand where the issue could be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network access to your RDS instances is controlled by a security group which acts somewhat like a firewall. Rules can be crafted in security groups to allow other members of that security group to connect to each other, which is the default policy in the default security group. Thus because your RDS instance and your EC2 instance are members of the same security group they can communicate freely but nothing else outside of that group can communicate with either host.

An instance can be a member of more than one security group at a time and if there are rules allowing the traffic in any of the security groups for which the instance is a member then the traffic will be allowed. In the spirit of security I would suggest not opening more ports than necessary and would not recommend opening ports within the default security group as that would effectively make those ports accessible on all instances in that security group.

So, to allow access to your Scaleway host:

1. Create a new security group from the VPC console, add a rule to this group that allows the MySQL port to be accessed from the IP address of your Scaleway host (or from anywhere, depending on your level of security concerns)
2. Attach that security group to your database in addition to the default security group through the RDS console